# regexp to match an IP address in python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the following regexp to match IP address,

```
x = 'IP is 200.185.24.24'
y = re.findall('([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-2][0-3])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])',x)
```

I am getting the following answer,

```
>>> y
[('200', '185', '24', '2')]
```

I have 2 questions here,

1. Why my mast octet is failing here. Rest works fine.
2. When you see my pattern above, I have repeated the same to match 2nd,3rd and 4th octet of an IP address. Is there a easy way to represent this repeated patterns. I guess \d in tcl is for repeat (not sure). I am looking for similar in python.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: There are several example regexes for matching IP addresses in The Regex Cookbook ch 7 at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html.

Answer (score 0):

Turn all the capturing groups present in your regex to non-capturing groups. And also it's better to use word boundaries or otherwise you have to reverse the pattern like `(?:large-pattern|medium-pattern|small-pattern)`

```
y = re.findall('\b(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-2][0-3])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\b',x)
```

You get the above output mainly because of `re.findall` function which gives the first preference to groups rather than matches. If there is no groups present then it gives the prefernce to matches.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I tried yours, but is returns an empty list,  >>> x = 'IP is 200.185.24.24'
>>> y = re.findall('\b(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-2][0-3])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5])\b',x)
>>>
>>> y
[]        ................. Appreciate your inputs.